# Django - Pass model name as parameter to generic view

Tags: django, django-generic-views

Let's say I have some Models that inherit from a base class, Animal. I can use generic views and route Cat/12 to a detail view and Dod/10 to the same detail view with a different context.
But I would like to get the Model name from the url so that I dont have to define a route.

I have something like this:

```
url(r'^cat/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
    DetailView.as_view(
        queryset=Cat.objects.filter(),
        model=Cat,
        context_object_name='animal',
        template_name='animal/detail.html'),
    name='detail'),
url(r'^dog/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
    DetailView.as_view(
        queryset=Dog.objects.filter(),
        model=Dog,
        context_object_name='animal',
        template_name='animal/detail.html'),
    name='detail'),
...
```

Obviously, this is too much repetitive code. I would rather do something like this:

```
url(r'^?P<my_animal>\w+/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
    DetailView.as_view(
        queryset=my_animal.objects.filter(),
        model=my_animal,
        context_object_name='animal',
        template_name='animal/detail.html'),
    name='detail'),
...
```

Can I do this?

**EDIT**

Here's what I ended up with, thanks to Darwin's help. It avoids the if/else to get the Model name:

```
class AnimalDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name='animal'
    template_name='animals/detail.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        my_animal = kwargs.get('my_animal', None)
        self.model = get_model('animals',my_animal.capitalize())
        try:
            ret = super(AnimalDetailView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except AttributeError:
            raise Http404
        return ret

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter()
```

Next time I have a question about Inheritance, I'll consult Darwin! LoL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can inherit from DetailView and override the *dispatch* method to build your own rules with something like this:

```
class AnimalDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name='animal'
    template_name='animal/detail.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        my_animal = kwargs.get('my_animal', None)
        if my_animal == 'dog':
            self.model = Dog
        elif my_animal == 'cat':
            self.model = Cat

        return super(AnimalDetailView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter()
```

and use an urlpattern like this:

```
url(r'^?P<my_animal>\w+/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', AnimalDetailView.as_view())
```

**Edit**:
I've make a mistake the last time because we can't instantiate a view class, just only using the 'as_view()' method. Try the new approach, I think this can help.

Comment: Kind of an unhelpful error: `This method is available only on the view class.`

Comment: See the code again, handler is defined after the AnimalDetailView, not inside it.

Comment: I have it defined outside of the AnimalDetailView class. In my views.py im importing using `from animals.views import handler`

Comment: Nice one, Darwin. Thanks for sticking with me on this! I'd vote you up but my reputation's not good enough. I guess Mother was right, :-(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any named parameters (i.e. `?P<my_animal>`) in your urls [will automatically be passed as keyword arguments to your views,](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/class-based-views/#dynamic-filtering):

> The key part to making this [Class Based Views] work is that when class-based views are called, various useful things are stored on self; as well as the request (self.request) this includes the positional (self.args) and name-based (self.kwargs) arguments captured according to the URLconf.

so you will have access to them as `self.kwargs['my_animal']` in the view.

If you [look at the `__init__` method of `BaseDetailView`](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.5/django.views.generic.detail/BaseDetailView/) (from which `DetailView` inherits) you'll see that all it is doing is taking the `kwargs` and assigning them to instance attributes, so you could easily do the following:

```
url(r'^?P<model>\w+/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',...
```

and the view should automatically assign the value passed in the URL to `self.model`. Of course you need to be careful and make sure to validate the input here, but it's a nice way to dynamically grab objects from models specified by the user

Comment: Sweet, but I'm doing it wrong, I guess: I'm getting `name 'my_plant' is not defined` in urls.py

Answer (score 1):

One other way to do it would be to pass your model directly instead of passing it through a variable

url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
# Common url
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.MoneyIndex.as_view(), name='money_index'),
    path('cat', views.CatListView.as_view(), name='cat_list'),
    path('dog', views.DogListView.as_view(), name='dog_list'),
    ]

# Dynamic url
MYMODELS = ['Cat','Dog',]
for modelX in MYMODELS:
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + [
        path('{0}/add'.format(modelX.lower()), views.MyCreateView.as_view(model=modelX), name='{0}_create'.format(modelX.lower())),
        path('{0}/<pk>'.format(modelX.lower()), views.MyDetailView.as_view(model=modelX), name='{0}_detail'.format(modelX.lower())),
        path('{0}/<pk>/upd'.format(modelX.lower()), views.MyUpdateView.as_view(model=modelX), name='{0}_update'.format(modelX.lower())),
        path('{0}/<pk>/del'.format(modelX.lower()), views.MyDeleteView.as_view(model=modelX), name='{0}_delete'.format(modelX.lower())),
    ]
```

view.py

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Cat, Dog
from .forms import CatForm, DogForm

class MyDetailView(generic.DetailView):     
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(MyDetailView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            modeltxt = self.model
            self.model = eval(modeltxt)


 class MyCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyCreateView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        modeltxt = self.model
        self.model = eval(modeltxt)
        self.form_class = eval('{0}Form'.format(modeltxt))
        self.success_url = reverse_lazy('{0}_list'.format(modeltxt.lower()))    


class MyUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyUpdateView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        modeltxt = self.model
        self.model = eval(modeltxt)
        self.form_class = eval('{0}Form'.format(modeltxt))
        self.success_url = reverse_lazy('{0}_list'.format(modeltxt.lower())) 


class MyDeleteView(generic.DeleteView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyDeleteView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        modeltxt = self.model
        self.model = eval(modeltxt)
        # Must be done because default points to modelname_confirm_delete.html
        self.template_name = 'appname/{0}_detail.html'.format(modeltxt.lower())
        self.success_url = reverse_lazy('{0}_list'.format(modeltxt.lower()))
```